# add a class to all day-divs when loading calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i need  to add the class 'modalbox' to all div's representing a day.
With that class I want to trigger a pop-up form.

Where or how do $( ".fc-day").addClass("modalbox");

PS I am just a snippet guy trying and putting all kind of things together...

Thx in advance

**edit 1**

This functions calls the fancybox which contains the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modalbox").fancybox();
    $("#contact").submit(function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

and this is how to call it (e.g.)

```
<p><a class="button modalbox" href="#inline">Contact Me</a></p>
```

(source: http://jenniferperrin.com/blog/jquery-tutorial-popup-modal-contact-form)

So I was thinking to add an onClick event provided in the jquery-ui FullCalendar
(http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick)

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    //here I need to trigger the fancybox-event
}
```

**edit 2**

Got it working. Added the class 'modalbox' to the td and then added this line inside the calendar options:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    $(".modalbox").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends.  If you really just need a snippet you can put it in a  tag at the bottom of the page.  However, if there are js files being loaded on the page itself then I'd recommend finding the one most relevant to your task and placing your snippet at the end of the file with a good comment explaining what you're doing and why.

Depending on your situation it might be necessary to implicitly iterate over all elements.  If that's the case I'd suggest:

```
$(".fc-day").each( function() {
  $(this).addClass("modalbox");
});
```

If implicit iteration is not necessary, what you have is fine.

Comment: The iteration was necessary, it worked but did not give me the right solution. Instead of popping up the form, it popped up the <td> I added the class to. Trying another solution (see edit)

Comment: In the case of your edit, have you considered `$(".modalbox").trigger('click');` in the portion of the day click function where you need to trigger your action?

Comment: JimP, no. What I did consider is to put the div that is inside the <td> in an anchor so I have <td><a class="modalbox" href="#inline"><div>...</div></a>. That works but in case of an empty <div> only one line will be clickable and not the whole cell

Comment: the trigger('click') does the job (too well). The form gets shown right away while my calendar doesn't get built. It only has to fire when I clicked on one of the days.

Comment: Ah, I see.  In the case that it's firing immediately, then wrap the trigger in an .onclick() and that should do what you need.
    $("#your-trigger").onclick( function() {
      $(".modalbox").trigger('click');
    });

Comment: can I somehow give the value of an attribute (data-date) from the td I've clicked on? I've tried this: $(document).ready(function() {
        var chosenDate = $("modalbox").data('date');
        $("#email").val(chosenDate); } but I don't see how it knows which one I clicked on...it doesn't work anyway. This is really fascinating but hard.

Comment: You can.  in your .onclick try this `var selected = $(this).attr('data-test'); console.log( selected );`.  That'll get you the value of the attribute 'data-test'.  You can fill in with whatever attribute you're looking for.  
If you're looking for a child element just do something more like ` var selected = $(this).find('a').val();`.  That'll specify which child your looking for and get the value of that element.

Comment: Ok, that is nice. I get the right value in the console. I now try to use it in the other script with var selectedDate = console.log($("#selected").val()); $(".modalbox").fancybox(); $("#email").val(selectedDate); but I get an empty field.

Comment: I'd recommend removing "console.log" from your variable declaration.  So it's more like `var selectedData = $("#selected").val(); ...`.  console.log is a completely separate function.

Comment: found it! Instead of putting the value in the textbox after fancybox was called, I've put it in immediately after clicking (so in the invisible form at that time) and then called the fancybox-popup. Thx for you help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite [render](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) method e.g. to add custom buttons or elements and events.